# Service registry in Eureka server with secured(HTTPS) client throwing exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl, microservices

I am new to implementing microservices trying to register in Netflix eureka server my client microservice is secured with an SSL certificate throwing "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

```
spring.application.name=gateway
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=https://localhost:8442/eureka/
eureka.server.wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty=100
eureka.instance.securePortEnabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lowerCaseServiceId=true

zuul.routes.authentication.path = /authentication/**
zuul.routes.authentication.url = https://localhost:8443/

spring.cloud.consul.host=localhost
spring.cloud.consul.port=8500
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.scheme=https

server.port=8442
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:eureka.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=test@123
#trust store location
trust.store=classpath:eureka.jks
#trust store password
trust.store.password=test@123
server.ssl.protocol=TLSv1
server.ssl.ciphers=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
@EnableZuulProxy
public class Gateway {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Gateway .class, args);
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class AuthenticationApplication {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthenticationApplication .class, args);
    }
}
```

```
spring.application.name=authentication
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=https://localhost:8442/eureka/
instance.hostname=localhost
server.port=8443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:client.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=test@123
#trust store location
trust.store=classpath:client.jks
#trust store password
trust.store.password=test@123
server.ssl.protocol=TLSv1
server.ssl.ciphers=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
```

```
 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forwardRequest(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:422)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forward(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:341)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.run(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:236)
    ... 63 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 84 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 90 common frames omitted
```